# how to join two datasets by key in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two datasets and each dataset have two elements.
Below are examples.

Data1: (name, animal)

```
('abc,def', 'monkey(1)')
('df,gh', 'zebra')
...
```

Data2: (name, fruit)

```
('a,efg', 'apple')
('abc,def', 'banana(1)')
...
```

Results expected: (name, animal, fruit)

```
('abc,def', 'monkey(1)', 'banana(1)')
...
```

I want to join these two datasets by using first column 'name.' I have tried to do this for a couple of hours, but I couldn't figure out. Can anyone help me?

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("abc").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val text1 = sc.textFile(args(0))
val text2 = sc.textFile(args(1))

val joined = text1.join(text2)
```

Above code is not working!

Comment: Where are you splitting the input text into `(key, value)` tuples?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What does it tell you?

Comment: @maasg It says ' 'cannot resolve symbol join.'

Comment: However, isn't it already has the format of (key, value) ? I'm really confused..

Comment: Can this be updated for datasets aswell  ? Solutions are only containing RDDs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`join` is defined on RDDs of pairs, that is, RDDs of type `RDD[(K,V)]`.
The first step needed is to transform the input data into the right type.

We first need to transform the original data of type `String` into pairs of `(Key, Value)`:

```
val parse:String => (String, String) = s => {
  val regex = "^\\('([^']+)',[\\W]*'([^']+)'\\)$".r
  s match {
    case regex(k,v) => (k,v)
    case _ => ("","")
  }
}
```

(Note that we can't use a simple `split(",")` expression because the key contains commas)

Then we use that function to parse the text input data:

```
val s1 = Seq("('abc,def', 'monkey(1)')","('df,gh', 'zebra')")
val s2 = Seq("('a,efg', 'apple')","('abc,def', 'banana(1)')")

val rdd1 = sparkContext.parallelize(s1)
val rdd2 = sparkContext.parallelize(s2)

val kvRdd1 = rdd1.map(parse)
val kvRdd2 = rdd2.map(parse)
```

Finally, we use the `join` method to join the two RDDs

```
val joined = kvRdd1.join(kvRdd2)
```

// Let's check out results

```
joined.collect

// res31: Array[(String, (String, String))] = Array((abc,def,(monkey(1),banana(1))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have one more question. How can I keep single quotes in data?

Comment: @tobby change the regex to preserve the quotes.

Comment: I tried  "^\\('([^']+)',[\\W]*'([^']+)'\\)$".. but it's not working?

Comment: if you don't want to modify the regex, you can always put back the quotes after parsing. Many ways to skin a cat, some are just faster than others.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create pairRDDs first for your data sets then you have to apply join transformation. Your data sets are not looking accurate.

Please consider the below example.

```
**Dataset1**

a 1
b 2
c 3

**Dataset2**

a 8
b 4
```

Your code should be like below in Scala

```
    val pairRDD1 = sc.textFile("/path_to_yourfile/first.txt").map(line => (line.split(" ")(0),line.split(" ")(1)))

    val pairRDD2 = sc.textFile("/path_to_yourfile/second.txt").map(line => (line.split(" ")(0),line.split(" ")(1)))

    val joinRDD = pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)

    joinRDD.collect
```

Here is the result from scala shell

```
res10: Array[(String, (String, String))] = Array((a,(1,8)), (b,(2,4)))
```