# Is Dataset.JoinWith the best way to join two datasets in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-dataset

I have two large datasets,

`val dataA : Dataset[TypeA]` and
`val dataB: Dataset[TypeB]`, where both `TypeA` and `TypeB` extend `Serializable`.

I want to join the two datasets on separate columns, so where `TypeA.ColumnA == TypeB.ColumnB`. Spark offers the function [`JoinWith`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#joinWith(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) on a dataset, which I think will do this properly, but the function is undocumented and marked as "experimental".

The other approach I have looked at is to use PairRDDs instead of datasets, and join them using a common key (like it says in this stackoverlow post here: [how to join two datasets by key in scala spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822377/how-to-join-two-datasets-by-key-in-scala-spark)).

Is there a specifically better approach to joining two datasets, or using either JoinWith or PairRDDs the best way?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462674/spark-dataset-api-join

Comment: That doesn't answer the question I asked though.

Comment: It depends on what you want the result type to be, JoinWith returns a `Dataset[(TypeA, TypeB)]` and the regular `join` will reutrn a `Dataset[Row]` (aka `DataFrame`) with the columns from both side of the join in a single flat structure like a normal sql join.